# Does AWS RDS charge you even if no connection is made in your DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For example, your DB is turned on 24/7 but you only performed connections to it (i.e., INSERT, UDPATE) for a total of 1 hour for the whole month. Are you going to be charged for a full month or just for an hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, AWS services are charging for *usage*, not for *time*.

In your case, the charge will roughly contain:
- General instance up-time (24/7)
- Amount of storage (size of db)
- Throughput (your INSERTS, UPDATES etc.)

The details - and thus the final fee - varies largely with the exact prizing scheme and instance size you have chosen.

Comment: So it's safe to say I will be charged a full month of up time since my DB is up for a full month even if my actual usage is only totaled 1 hour.

Comment: Yep. If actual traffic is low, then the full charge at the end of the month will be affordable, but nevertheless you pay for availability, not for usage.

Comment: "AWS services are charging for usage, not for time" while true in a sense, masks the fact that RDS is "using" instance hardware and EBS storage for the entire "time" that it's running, whether it's accessed or not.  What you are "using" with an RDS instance are things that could loosely called "instance hours" and "storage hours," neither of which goes away until you delete the RDS instance.

Comment: @Michael That's what I wanted to say. But admittedly my wording could be clearer...